# Failing to install Kali Linux - SQUASHFS Error

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install `Kali Linux 2019.2 - amd64.iso` using `live installer`.
I am using `Graphic install` and it is failing at: **Install the system**

I have checked all the documentation from Kali.org and read other StackExchange QAs, but nothing seems to mention the issue I am facing.

I am using `kali-linux-2019.2-amd64.iso` image downloaded from Official Kali website and checked the `SHA 256 sum`.

I checked the logs on `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F4`, which showed the following (mentioning only the `debug`, `warning` and `error` logs):

```
DEBUG: resolver (libgcc1): package doesn't exist (ignored) // This comes multiple times
DEBUG: resolver (fat-modules): package doesn't exist (ignored)
DEBUG: resolver (scsi-modules): package doesn't exist (ignored)
// Other modules were retrived successfully
```

**Main issue (I think)**

```
SQUASHFS error: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x1d887cf1
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [1d887cf1]
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 1d887cf1, size 1fd9c
```

and this repeats around 30-40 times after which I get:

```
base-installer: error: The tar process copying the olive system failed (only 31768 out of 424715 files have been copied, last file was ).
(process:11562): tar: read error: Input/output error
(process:11562): tar: short read
WARNING **: Configuring 'live-installer' failed with error code 1
WARNING **: Menu item 'live-installer' failed
```

**Details regarding the step: Partition disks:**

I chose `Guided partition` | `Choose entire disk` | `All files in one partition`

**Details regarding target hard disk**

I have tried the installation on two internal hard disks:

1. (1 TB) The first internal hard disk I tried currently has no operating system on it. I have wiped the entire disk with `DBAN` (quick option)
2. (1 TB) The second is an internal hard disk that I am using with an external SATA to USB 3.0/2.0 cable. I have cleaned its partition table using

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=2048 count=32
   ```

The installation fails with the exact same log for both cases

**Details regarding the bootable USB:**

It's a 16GB pen drive. I tried both `MBR` and `GPT` partitioning schemes (although I don't think it matters for the live installer USB). I have formatted it to `FAT` format. I then use the `dd` command (mentioned below) to create the live installer.

**Note:**

1. I am creating the bootable USB on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` (Kernel: `4.18.0-25-generic`) using the following command:

   ```
   sudo dd if=kali-linux-2019.2-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
   ```
2. I have tried both `UEFI` and `BIOS` mode. In `UEFI` mode, I get the following error:

   ```
   Selected boot image did not authenticate
   ```

Comment: Have you tried different USB creators and/or other USBs?

Comment: I only have access to an Ubuntu system. I tried using `Unetbootin` (Unable to mount CD-ROM, which was caused because it needs to be created using `dd`). Also tried using `Universal USB installer` using `Wine`, but I get black screen when I start the installer. Yes, I have tried using a 32 GB pen drive as well.

Comment: Try [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)

Comment: Oh sorry! Forgot to mention. Tried Etcher as well. I get `Problem reading data from CD-ROM`. It is not able to find all the packages as I see from the `syslog`.